# Finding a residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am given $f(z) = \frac{\text{Log} z}{(z^2 + 1)^2}$. The singularity point occurs at $z = i$, with a pole order of $m = 2$. How can I go about finding $\text{Res}_{z=i} f(z)$? The correct answer should be $\frac{\pi+2i}{8}$ but I do not know how my exercise got this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$${\rm Res}_{z=i} f(z)=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{d}{dz}\left(f(z)(z-i)^2\right)
=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{\log z}{(z+i)^2}=
\lim_{z\to i}\frac{\frac{1}{z}(z+i)^2-2(z+i)\log z}{(z+i)^4}
$$
$$=\frac{-i(2i)^2-4i\log i}{(2i)^4}=\frac{4i-4i\frac{i\pi}{2}}{16}=\frac{2i+\pi}{8}.$$

It can also be computed by Cauchy's extended integral formula:
$${\rm Res}_{z=i} f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-i|=r} f(z)\,dz
=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-i|=r} \frac{\log z/(z+i)^2}{(z-i)^2}\,dz$$
$$=\lim_{z\to i}\frac{d}{dz}\left(f(z)(z-i)^2\right).$$

Comment: Is this part of using Cauchy's *extended* integral formula? (the formula for derivatives?)

Comment: I've used the fact that the ${\rm Res}$ is equal to $c_{-1},$ where $c_k$s are the Laurent coefficients.